# Вычисление суммы ряда с факториалом

Tags: java, математика

Подскажите, что не так? Хочу посчитать вот такую формулу: `1 + 1/1! + 1/2! .... + 1/n!`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phill {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int x = n;
        int[] a = new int[n];
        n = n + 1;
        int g = n;
        for (x=n-1;x < 0;x = x-1) {
            a[x] = g;
            g = g - 1;
        }
        n = n - 1;
        int c = 1;
        while (n>0) {
            x = 0;

            while(a[x] <= n) {
                c = a[x]*c;
                x=x+1;
            }
            n = n - 1;
            int d = 1;
            d = 1/c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int d = 1/c;`.

Comment: `System.out.println(2.718281828459045);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, данный цикл не имеет смысла

```
for (x=n-1;x < 0;x = x-1){
           ^^^^^
```

так как изначально, как я понимаю, значение `x` является положительным. а потому цикл ни разу не выполнится из-за условия `x < 0`.

Также нет никакого смысла в этих предложениях

```
       x = 0;

        while(a[x] <= n) {
            c = a[x]*c;
            x=x+1;
        }
        n = n - 1;
        int d = 1;
        ^^^^^^^^^
        d = 1/c;
        ^^^^^^^^^
    }
```

Вы объявляете локальную переменную `d` в конце тела цикла, и эта переменная сразу же уничтожается.

Имейте в виду, что для хранения вычислений по вашей формуле нужно объявлять переменные как числа с плавающий запятой и соответственно вычислять выражения. Также учтите, что целые числа ограничены, а потому они могут хранить факториал лишь для ограниченного значения.

У вас много в программе бессмысленного кода, как, например, этот

```
    n = n + 1;
    ^^^^^^^^^^
    int g = n;
    for (x=n-1;x < 0;x = x-1) {
        a[x] = g;
        g = g - 1;
    }
    n = n - 1;
    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Вместо двух выделенных предложений вы могли бы просто написать

```
    int g = n + 1;
```

EDIT: Я не силен в Java (то есть совсем его не знаю), как и в прочих языках программирования, но пользуясь здравым смыслом, я бы написал программу следующим образом

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Demo
{
    private static double calculate( int n )
    {
        double result = 0.0;
        double factorial = 1.0;

        for ( int i = 0; i <= n; i++, factorial /= i )
        {
            result += factorial;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

        do
        {
            n = 0;

            System.out.print( "Enter a non-negative number: " );

            n = scan.nextInt();
        } while ( ! ( n > 0 ) );                

        System.out.println( "The result is equal to " + calculate( n ) );
    }
}
```

Если ввести число `10`, то результат будет следующим

```
Enter a non-negative number: 10
The result is equal to 2.7182818011463845
```

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, что помогаете, но все равно, это не решение.

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас переделаю

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем коде Вы совершаете массу каких-то не очень понятных манипуляций.

Все намного проще:

```
int n = 10; // Количество членов ряда, считаем, что 1/1! – это первый член ряда
double sum = 1;
double summand = 1;
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    summand *= ((double) 1/i);
    sum += summand;
}

System.out.println(sum);
```